# Java let me define a static method in an interface

Tags: java

```
public interface B {
    String iname = "TBA";
    int iid = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

    public static void goForIt() {
        System.out.println("Went for it");
    }

    public void doSomething();

}
```

And now...

```
public class D {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B.goForIt();
    }
}
```

This successfully printed "Went for it". I was told that interfaces cannot have static methods though. So, what's going on here? However, when I have a class implement B, then the static method doesn't work.

Comment: Try compiling on Java 7.

Comment: Hmmm...I think I'm using the latest JDK 8.

Comment: This was added in Java 8.

Comment: Oh...does it change this particular property of interface then?

Comment: It changes a whole host of things. In fact, it changes so many things that reading literature on anything pre Java 8 is probably not a good idea.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes. Design simple imperative language with garbage collector -> get mindshare based on easy learning curve -> add generics -> add lambdas -> now a functional programming language with mindshare

Answer (score 3):

[Java 8 has introduced](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/enhancements.html) the ability to have `static` methods in interfaces.

> Enhancements in Java SE 8
>
> ... In addition, you can define static methods in interfaces.

But `static` methods are still not inherited, either from implementing an interface or from a superclass.